# Custom field template sorting

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the [Custom Field Template](http://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-field-template/) plugin for my website.

Right now I see my custom fields are getting sorted by `meta_id ASC`. For my application I want to bring two specific fields to the top. I don't want to touch the plugin code, is there a way of doing it otherwise?

Comment: Are you using WP_Query? If so, can you post what you have so far?

Comment: What is the name of the plugin?

Comment: It is the "custom field template" plugin. @Rob: The query is just a select for fields from wp_postmeta table and they are in wp-admin files.